# PHP: can not exec a script in the background

Tags: php, background, exec

I have main php script on web-server nginx+php-fpm and try to run another php script in background using GET request from web-browser. Line code in main.php to call detect.php:

```
exec("/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/detect.php 6 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

detect.php **does not start**. I don't have any errors.

If to remove "&":

```
exec("/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/detect.php 6 > /dev/null 2>&1 ");
```

detect.php starts successfully.

From shell bash with "&" :

```
 sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/detect.php 6 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Script detect.php starts successfully.

Comment: I need run detect.php in background! There are many other actions and other scripts in main.php. I can not wait while detect.php finish.

Comment: Can you run it synchronously after the connection to the client is closed?

Answer (score 0):

try this and make sure your php path are correct

```
        $dir=dirname(__FILE__);
        $file_name="detect.php"; 
        $php_path="/usr/bin/php"; 

        $args = array(6); 

        $command1="cd $dir";
        $command2="$php_path  $file_name ".implode(" ",$args) ." > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &";

        $final_command=$command1."; ".$command2;
        shell_exec($final_command);
```

Comment: No success, user www-data does not have shell in /etc/passwd and can not run "cd" command.

Comment: @AndreyAndreev i test this code on local (MAMP , php7 ) and also on server (CentOS , php 5.6 ) and works , are exec method works ? try exec("mkdir test_dir")

Comment: I am shure exec works. In my post I wrote : without "&" = background detect.php starts and works correctly. detect.php can create log in /tmp/ and do many other jobs, I checked .